# Unable to assign drive letter to non-booting VHDX

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, windows-8.1, vhdx

I am trying to get a virtual file server (Windows 8.1 Pro, inherited) running on Windows Server 2016 (Standard).  In Hyper-V Manager, I can create a Gen 2 VM (when I tried Gen 1, I couldn't get past the black screen with the blinking cursior) and add the virtual boot disk.  I had to try this a couple of times as the first time the VHDX refused to mount properly (assuming corruption).

The VM boots without a problem.  However, when I use Hyper-V Manager to add either one (or both) of two other > 1 TB VHDX files, I cannot access them.  They only show up in Disk Management (not Explorer) and I can do very little with them: Convert to Dynamic Disk, Offline, Properties, Help

**Disk Management screen**

[image: Disk Management screen]

All of the virtual disk files reside on an external 8 TB USB drive.

I tried adding one of the the data disks before adding the boot disk (thinking there is an order dependency), but the end result was the same.  I also tried doing this through the command line as well as directly in Disk Management itself (as opposed to using Hyper-V Manager, per above).

This shouldn't be a problem as I've done this before (though with Server 2012 and R2) a number of times.  I have not been able to find anything on the web (that worked) after several hours of searching.

**Update (9/4/2018):**

Per **A Newgate's** request below, I've added the following information:

chkdsk was clean on all mount points for both the physical and virtual drives.

**Physical disks (disk 1 contains the VDHX files)**

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online         7452 GB      0 B        *
```

**Physical Disk 0:**

```
HGST HTS721010A9E630
Disk ID: {BBFCDBD1-6C63-4959-B9E9-0D11D2D98F4B}
Type   : SATA
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1700)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label      Fs     Type        Size    Status   Info
  ----------  ---  --------  -----  ----------  -------  -------  ----
  Volume 1     C             NTFS   Partition    930 GB  Healthy  Boot
  Volume 2         Recovery  NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy  Hidden
  Volume 3                   FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy  System
```

**Physical disk 1:**

```
Seagate Expansion Desk SCSI Disk Device
Disk ID: {9323BA28-14F4-4CBD-88D4-477EE55C200D}
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
There are no volumes. 

The second time I ran 'detail disk', a volume did show:

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type         Size   Status   Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ---------   ------  -------  ----
  Volume 4     E   Seagate Exp  NTFS   Partition  7451 GB  Healthy
```

**Virtual Disks: (Disk 1 is the boot drive)**

```
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1853 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
```

**Virtual Disk 0:**

```
Microsoft Virtual Disk
Disk ID: 0AF949B8
Type   : SAS
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
There are no volumes.
```

**Virtual Disk 1:**

```
Microsoft Virtual Disk
Disk ID: {4C0FB1C3-2E4D-4FC4-87E3-E9D580C728CF}
Type   : SAS
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 2
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs    Type       Size    Status   Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  ----  ---------  ------  -------  --------
  Volume 1     C   Windows      NTFS  Partition  150 GB  Healthy  Boot
  Volume 2     D                NTFS  Partition  764 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3         Windows RE   NTFS  Partition  800 MB  Healthy  Hidden
  Volume 4         BOOT         FAT32 Partition  260 MB  Healthy  System
  Volume 5         Recovery im  NTFS  Partition   15 GB  Healthy  Hidden
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have backups because chkdsk can corrupt the file system

Try to run FSUTIL fsinfo drives or diskpart -> list disk -> select disk X -> detail disk and share the results.

Run chkdsk using mount point instead of drive letter - mountvol to gather all the mount points
chkdsk "\?\Volume{eb38d03c-29ed-11e2-be65-806e6f6e6963}" as an example.

Comment: chkdsk on the physical drive (presumably external drive containing the VHDX), or the virtual drive, or the original source (physical) drive?

Comment: virtual drives those are VHDXs. please also share diskpart or fstutil output from both the VM and host.